# Spring ClientHttpRequestInterceptor Explanation

Tags: java, spring, http, web-deployment, implementation

I'm not sure how the interceptor works and what it is useful for. Also, why use the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor over AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor (or vice versa)?

In particular:

Should the intercept function be implemented on the front-end and back-end or is the back-end sufficient? How, where and when is the function called and how does data get passed to the function?

The only difference I can see between the regular interceptor and async from the docs is that in the regular you have the option to "wrap the response to filter HTTP attributes" and in async you have the option to "adapt the response to filter HTTP attributes with the help of the abstract class ListenableFutureAdapter."